# Animation on the Button can not be run only one time

Tags: android, animation, android-button

I have some problems with animated buttons in android. This is my code:

```
     private void RunAnimations() {
            Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
            a.reset();
            Button tv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            tv.clearAnimation();
            tv.startAnimation(a);}

            @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
            if(event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                RunAnimations();
            }
            return false;
            }
```

The problem is the animation will run if the screen OnTouch. I want the animation to run only one time. What should I add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `boolean` to your class `animationRun = false`, then

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        if(!animationRun && event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            RunAnimations();
            animationRun = true;
        }
        return false;
        }
```

I'd prefer to just remove the event handler after you play the animation, but I don't really know the Android API so can't help you there.